# Why is my script telling me that my Minecraft server on port 25565 is unreachable?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

My Python script is not working properly. It says that `kandicraft.finlaydag33k.nl` on port `25565` is down, whilst, it's responding to pings (and I can connect to the game itself)

I know it should be a bug somewhere in the code, but I can't find it as I started python like half an hour ago.

The output that I get is: `24-02-2016 16:05:30] kandicraft.finlaydag33k.nl on port 25565 seems to be unreachable!`
I've editted the question as the port 80 with google now works, but the main purpose of this script (pinging minecraft servers) later on doesn't.
the error I get from the exception is `an integer is required` (so port `25565` doesn't seem to be an integer???)

```
import os
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
import socket

## set variables for the machine to ping and pin for the LED
hostname = ['kandicraft.finlaydag33k.nl:25565','google.com:80']
led_pin = 37

## prepare
led_status = gpio.LOW
gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(led_pin, gpio.OUT, gpio.PUD_OFF, led_status)

## PING FUNCTION GALORE!!
def check_ping(host,port):
    captive_dns_addr = ""
    host_addr = ""
    try:
        host_addr = socket.gethostbyname(host)

        if (captive_dns_addr == host_addr):
            return False

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(1)
        s.connect((host,port))
        s.close()
    except:
        return False

    return True



## Run the script itself infinitely
while True:
    host_up = ""
    for host in hostname:
        if ":" in host:
            temphost, tempport = host.split(":")
            pingstatus = check_ping(temphost, tempport)
            if pingstatus == False:
                print('[' + time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") + '] ' + temphost + ' on port ' + tempport + ' seems to be unreachable!')
                host_up = "False"

    if host_up == "False":
        led_status = gpio.HIGH
    else:
        led_status = gpio.LOW
    gpio.output(led_pin,led_status)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Don't post links to code, post the code in the question.

Comment: Please post the output that your program returns

Comment: Wow! You're doing pretty well for someone who "started python like half an hour ago". Or did someone else write that code... ?

Comment: @PM2Ring well... the `check_ping()` has been copied of a python site the rest is just alot of google...

Comment: I'm going to guess that the problem isn't with your code, but with your connection. Your raspberry-pi isn't connecting to the internet at all.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I have tested that with `ping google.com` but it says it's responding.

Comment: To debug your program just replace `except:` by `except Exception as exc:` and add `print exc` just after before `return False` in the `check_ping()` function

Comment: @FinlayRoelofs - I think you need to be more detailed here, since we're talking about multiple machines. When you say you tested it with `ping google.com`, are you saying that you did that from the Raspberry Pi or from your main computer?

Comment: FWIW using a bare `except` is generally dangerous, since it will indiscriminately catch exceptions, not just the one you're expecting.

Comment: @PM2Ring ah. in the answer of massiou you can see that port 80 works now, but port 25565 (as I will be mainly testing that port lateron) throws me `an integer is required`

Comment: I don't know why `'80'` works; port numbers should be numbers, not strings. So you'll need to use `int()` to do the conversion.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, I added it (see my answer below) and now it works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve all issues that I found by using `check_ping(temphost,int(tempport))`
thanks all for helping me solve it!

Answer (score 2):

To debug your program just replace

```
except:
    return False
```

by:

```
except Exception as exc:
    print exc
    return False
```

in `check_ping()` function

Comment: I managed to get port 80 to work, but for a test I tried it with port 25565 (as I want to check that port too in the script lateron) but then I get `an integer is required`

Comment: @FinlayRoelofs - Huh. That might be the C level code having an issue with that number being too big to fit in an int on your Raspberry Pi? I don't know how big ints are on that.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare how do i see how big ints are on a pi?